# В SOAP не обрабатывается запрос из-за отсутствия xmlns:ns1

Tags: soap

Добрый день! Я использую для тестирования SOAP запросов программму SOAP UI.

Есть WSDL сервис на который я отправляю запрос, есть два запроса, в одном из запросов в шапке прописано  xmlins=ns1... и далее ns1 фигурирует в каждом теге.

*Пример удачного запроса с ns1*

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/blabla" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  <SOAP-ENV:Body>    <ns1:CALC_DATA>      <ns1:UserLogin>123</ns1:UserLogin>
```

*Пример неудачного запроса без ns1 (шапка выглядит иначе).*

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <S:Body>
<CALC_DATA xmlns="http://tempuri.org/blabla"> <UserLogin>123</UserLogin>
```

Данный запрос не обрабатывается. (на него даже ответ с ошибкой не приходит, т.е. сервис просто игноирирует данный запрос).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше поступить в данном случае.

Comment: Лучше указывать namespace в каждом тэге, как и просят.